# Problem with Matrix/File Manager

Tags: matrix, file-manager

When trying to add an image the following problems occur:

EE v2.5.0.
Matrix 2.2.2.1

Select '+ Add Image' the File Manager opens correctly, but the navigation is broken, and 'Show files as' seems to have no effect. The error when trying to navigate to a previous page of images is:
'C=content_publish&M=filemanager_actions&action=directory_contents&tbl_offset=15'

So I upgraded EE and Matrix:

EE v2.5.4.
Matrix 2.5.4

But when I select '+ Add Image' nothing happens.

I think I have pinned the problem down to the Themes/third_party/matrix/ directory, as if I change this directory back to its old version, 2.2.2.1, File Manager opens but I get the original problem with navigation.

Comment: Howdy - If you open up your browser's debug console, do you see any JS errors?  That is the first place to start. thank you!

Comment: nope, no js errors, for old or new version.

Comment: Is it possible to get Super Admin and FTP details to this site? If so I'd be happy to look at it directly, please email those details to support@pixelandtonic.com.  Thank you!